# BIQQUERY - Summing previews 30 days

Tags: sql, sum, google-bigquery, intervals

I am trying to sum up for each date the previews 30 days, however, it's not summing anything
In the following SQL I try to get for order date X all the orders that came for If Date >= Date -30days then SUM(Orders of last 30 days) END

```
SELECT 
  a.Shop_Country
  ,a.order_date
  ,a.Order_Week
  ,SUM(a.number_Orders) as orders
  ,CASE WHEN a.Order_Date >= DATE_ADD(b.Order_Date, -30, "day") THEN SUM(a.number_Orders) ELSE 0 END as total_orders
FROM
  [marketing-int:finance_report.overall_view] a
JOIN [marketing-int:finance_report.overall_view] b
  ON a.Order_Date = b.Order_Date

GROUP BY
  a.Shop_Country
  ,a.Order_Date
  ,b.Order_Date
  ,a.Order_Week
  ,a.Order_Channel
  ,a.number_Orders
```

Comment: So what does this do? Are we supposed to guess what is happening here?

Comment: remove  a.number_orders from group by clause

Comment: Some more information would help. Are you getting a syntax error? Is the query failing? What are you trying to do? The more info you give, the more easily we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Hi, so what I try to do it to sum up the previews 30 days of orders, so for date X return me all orders coming from Date >= Date-30 and sum them into one number

Comment: My guess on why so many downvotes: A lot of people look at the `sql` and `sum` tags, and they might not appreciate the style of this question. Going for the `google-bigquery` tag only might find you a less daunting audience next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT 
  Shop_Country
  ,order_date
  ,Order_Week
  ,SUM(number_Orders) OVER(PARTITION BY Shop_Country ORDER BY Order_Date 
      RANGE BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS total_orders  
FROM
  [marketing-int:finance_report.overall_view]
```

Hope this will be good start for you

See `window-frame-clause` section of [Window functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#windowfunctions) for more details